# How can I see the correct "private bytes" value in process explorer?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory, process-explorer

I have a process that intentionally uses large amounts of memory. When I view this process in Process Explorer's list view with all memory-related columns enabled, this is what I see:

[image]

Note that all the values are in the <1MB range. However, if I click properties on that process and go to the performance-graph page, I see this:

[image: Process Explorer's properties dialog]

I believe 788.6 MB to be the correct memory usage for this process because it corresponds to how much I have allocated. How can I get process explorer to show this figure in a column in the main window?

I'm almost ready to call this a bug because there is a column named "Private Bytes", exactly the same name as the number in the properties dialog, yet it shows a vastly different value.

Comment: Are you running Process Explorer as administrator?

Comment: Yes. (aaand I need 11 more characters to be allowed to post this comment).